# Перемешиватель символов в строке

Tags: c#

Приложение должно перемешивать символы в заданной строке и выводить все вариации этих перемешиваний, но выводит только один вариант несколько раз.

```
string str = "RNDSTR";
string genStr = "";
int combNum = str.Length * str.Length;
string[] abbs = new string[combNum];
char[] chr = str.ToCharArray();

Random rnd = new Random();

Console.WriteLine(combNum);
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    genStr += chr[rnd.Next(1, str.Length)];
    if (i+1==str.Length)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < abbs.Length; j++)
        {
            if (abbs[j]==genStr)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                abbs[j] = genStr;
                Console.WriteLine(genStr+"\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете показать какой должен быть результат? Нужно сгенерировать все возможные перестановки строки? Или несколько случайных? Символы могут повторяться (`RDRRSR`)?

Comment: Такая задача достаточно просто решается с помощью рекурсии

Answer (score 0):

В английской терминологии эта задача называется `Get all permutations`. Данный код выводит все возможные перестановки символов строки без повторений. За основу взят код c сайта [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string-2/).

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    private static void Permute(string str, int l, int r) 
    { 
        if (l == r) 
            Console.WriteLine(str); 
        else
        { 
            for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
            { 
                str = Swap(str, l, i); 
                Permute(str, l + 1, r); 
                str = Swap(str, l, i); 
            } 
        } 
    }

    public static string Swap(string str, int i, int j) 
    {
        var charArray = str.ToCharArray();
        char temp = charArray[i];
        charArray[i] = charArray[j]; 
        charArray[j] = temp;
        return new String(charArray);
    } 

    public static void Main() 
    { 
        const string str = "RNDSTR";
        Permute(str, 0, str.Length - 1);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Учтите, что в строке автора есть повторы, поэтому будут генерироваться лишние перестановки. Лучше использовать какой-нибудь аналог next_permutation

Comment: Хм, действительно. Это можно поправить

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что в строке символы могут повторяться, т. е. это перестановки с повторениями.
Они несложно реализуются с помощью рекурсии и итератора. Ниже пример программы, выводящей построчно в лексикографическом порядке всевозможные различные перестановки введенной строки:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Permutations
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите строку:");

            var str = Console.ReadLine();

            var comb = new Combinatorics();
            var numb = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("\nПерестановки:\n");

            foreach (var permutation in comb.Permutation(str))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(permutation);
                numb++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"\nОбщее число перестановок: {numb}");
        }
    }        

    public class Combinatorics
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Permutation(string s)
        {
            if (s == string.Empty)
                yield return string.Empty;
            else
            {
                var set = new SortedSet<char>(s);

                foreach (var ch in set)
                {
                    var substring = (new StringBuilder(s).Remove(s.IndexOf(ch), 1)).ToString();
                    foreach (var p in Permutation(substring))
                        yield return ch + p;    
                }
            }          
        }
    }
}
```